# select specific img using this selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a problem using `this` slector.
I have a couple of divs with pictures in them. And i applied a class to the pictures to make them gray-scale and when i hover the link i would like them to remove the class.
The html would be somehting like this:

```
div class="box">
    <a class="articol" href="#">
      <img src="image.jpg">
      <p>some text</p>
    </a>
</div>
div class="box">
    <a class="articol" href="#">
      <img src="image.jpg">
      <p>some text</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the js would be somehting like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.articol").hover(function(){
     $(".box img.desaturate").removeClass('desaturate');
  }, function() {
     $(".box img").addClass('desaturate');
});});
```

The only problem is that i want only the image that i am hovering to remove the `.desaturate` class. But it removes the class from all images.

Comment: there is no img.desaturate element in code you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.articol').hover(function(){
     $(this).children('img').removeClass('desaturate');
  }, function() {
     $(this).children('img').addClass('desaturate');
});
```

Comment: No worries, hit the green tick! As you can see there are many ways to skin a cat with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("a.articol").hover(function(){
     $(this).find("img.desaturate").removeClass('desaturate');
  }, function() {
     $(this).find("img").addClass('desaturate');
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(function() {
  $("a.articol").hover(function(){
     $(".box img.desaturate").removeClass('desaturate');
     $(this).addClass('desaturate');;
  });

  $("a.articol").blur(function(){
     $(".box img.desaturate").removeClass('desaturate');
  });
});
```